# Update two partial views when any column gets updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a page in which there are two partial views, one to the left and the other to the right. I would like these two views to be refreshed automatically when the tables that they are related to gets updated. Is SignalR the best option? and Is it complicated to implement this to an existing project? Right now I am using javascript 'set interval' to update every few seconds. Instead of doing constant polling I want to update the views only when the data gets refreshed. I am new to SignalR.
This is a ASP.NET mvc project,I want to update these two views only when the information pertaining to this user gets updated.
Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a better option when compared to requesting for update in a regular interval since SignalR solution gives you more instant updates on your UI.

In your case, you might have to send out broadcasts from the server as soon as you update the backend tables.

> Is it complicated to implement this to an existing project?

That's upto the architecture of your project, however implementing it in an MVC application is not so hard.

[Here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) is an example of how SignalR is implemented in an MVC project.

Comment: Appreciate your time.